# Creating an MVC Layout that has a sidebar sometimes and other times not

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

In my asp.net MVC application I have a two types of pages. One with a sidebar and one without a sidebar. I would like to achieve this using only one _Layout. Can someone give me advice on how to do this using the mvc templating system.

So in some cases I would like my main content to span all 12 columns and in other cases I would like a 2 column sidebar and the main content spanning 10 columns. Is there any way to achieve this using Sections?

Comment: How do you determine if/when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally detect if a Layout Section Has Been Implemented or not using `IsSectionDefined` inside your `_Layout`:

```
<div class="container body-content">

    @RenderSection("sideBar", false)

    @if (!IsSectionDefined("sideBar"))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        @RenderBody()
    }


    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

So if the side bar is not defined, it simply render a 12 column div for you. otherwise you can define side bar in each page you want:

```
@section sideBar
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            SideBar
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: This is a *clever* way to accomplish what he wants, but he hasn't really said enough of how he determines when to post an appropriate answer IMHO.

Comment: Not sure why people dislike this post. I feel like it was pretty straight forward. Sirwan seemed to understand it! Thanks for the perfect response.